# changing scale of date on x-axis in line plot in R

Tags: r

I have two issues in this plot

1- I have this dataset and would like to have a line plot with multiple lines each represent total number of injury cause during 3 months. So, the x-axis should be separated into blucks of 3 months and data represented in the figure should reflect frequency of each injury cause in three months.

x-axis should have year and month (date_labels="%Y %b")

2- Road traffic accidents are more frequent than other causes of injuries; thus, I would like to have two y axis scales (one on the left as usual and one on the right). the one on the right will have a scale that fits the number of "traffic accidents" (from 1 to 150 by 10) and the other one (from 1 to 80 by 10) will indicate number of other causes of injuries.
traffic accidents should be linked to the right scale and the other causes should be linked to the left scale.

```
    Date              Injury.Cause  n
1   2019-03-25         Falls from height  1
2   2019-03-25     Falls on level ground  3
3   2019-03-25    Road traffic accidents  3
4   2019-03-26    Road traffic accidents  5
5   2019-03-27     Falls on level ground  3
6   2019-03-27    Road traffic accidents  3
7   2019-03-28     Falls on level ground  2
8   2019-03-28    Road traffic accidents  3
9   2019-03-29     Falls on level ground  4
10  2019-03-29    Road traffic accidents  9
11  2019-03-30         Falls from height  2
12  2019-03-30     Falls on level ground  2
13  2019-03-30    Road traffic accidents  7
14  2019-03-31     Falls on level ground  1
15  2019-03-31    Road traffic accidents  1
16  2019-04-01     Falls on level ground  3
17  2019-04-02 Assaults related injuries  1
18  2019-04-02     Falls on level ground  1
19  2019-04-02    Road traffic accidents  2
20  2019-04-03         Falls from height  2
```

I tried this code

```
ggplot(df) + aes(Date, n, color = Injury.Cause) + geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", breaks =  "3 months" , date_labels="%Y %b",limits = c(min(df$Date), max(df$Date)))
```

and I got a really crowded figure because it used number of cases/day (below)

[image]

thank you in advance

Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the other answer, here's a complete response including the other y-axis. *Note that the first (long) step involves creating test data*, so in future it would be helpful if you can provide the input data. This code should work with your data, but I can't guarantee it.

### Set Up Test Data

This creates a dataframe called `df` with random numbers for daily accident rates. The daily rate for Traffic Accidents is about five times higher.

```
# load packages
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

# creating dummy data
# set up low-value categories
categories <- c("Falls on level ground", "Falls from height", "Assaults Related Injuries")

# set up all the dates
dates <- seq.Date(from = lubridate::ymd("2019-01-01"), 
                  to = lubridate::ymd("2021-06-30"),
                  by = "day")

# create a data frame with injury stats for each day from 2019-01-01 to 2021-06-30
# Road traffic accidents are much higher, ranging from 40-50 per day
df <- tibble(Date =  rep(dates, times = length(categories)),
             Injury.Cause = rep(categories, times = length(dates)),
             n = sample(x = 0:10,
                        size = length(categories) * length(dates),
                        replace = TRUE)) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(Date = dates,
                   Injury.Cause = "Road Traffic Accidents",
                   n = sample(10:20,
                              size = length(dates),
                              replace = TRUE)))
```

### Creating Quarterly Sums

This code rounds each date down to beginning of the quarter and then creates quarterly sums. One advantage of this approach over the other answer is that these can then be plotted using a date x-axis.

```
# now group data by quarter by rounding dates down to the nearest quarter,
# then summing results.
df_rounded <- df %>%
  mutate(quarter_floor = lubridate::floor_date(Date, unit = "quarter")) %>%
  group_by(quarter_floor, Injury.Cause) %>%
  summarise(n_quarter = sum(n))

# make a single plot showing all values on one axis
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df_rounded,
            mapping = aes(x = quarter_floor,
                          y = n_quarter, 
                          color = Injury.Cause))
```

### Plotting With a Second Y-Axis

Putting two y-axes on the same plot is confusing and isn't often recommended, but here's how to do it. This solution creates two separate data frames, one for the left-hand axis and one for the right-hand axis.

The trick is that the y-values in the second data frame are *scaled* to normalize their range them against the values in the left-hand column, and then the second axis is scaled to show the original range.

```
# set up a plot with two seaprately scaled axes.
# set up the first dataframe with the low-valued entries
df_for_plot_1 <- df %>%
  mutate(quarter_floor = lubridate::floor_date(Date, unit = "quarter")) %>%
  group_by(quarter_floor, Injury.Cause) %>%
  summarise(n_quarter = sum(n)) %>%
  filter(Injury.Cause != "Road Traffic Accidents")

# set up a second dataframe with only the high-value accidents.
# create scaled values so that the largest road accident sum equals the largest
# of the other accident sums.
df_for_plot_2 <- df %>%
  mutate(quarter_floor = lubridate::floor_date(Date, unit = "quarter")) %>%
  group_by(quarter_floor, Injury.Cause) %>%
  summarise(n_quarter = sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(Injury.Cause == "Road Traffic Accidents") %>%
  mutate(n_quarter_scaled = n_quarter / (max(n_quarter) / max(df_for_plot_1$n_quarter)) )


# now plot both dataframes on the same plot, with a second y-axis that maps
# the scaped road-accident values back to the original values
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df_for_plot_1,
            mapping = aes(x = quarter_floor,
                          y = n_quarter, 
                          color = Injury.Cause))+
  geom_line(data = df_for_plot_2,
            mapping = aes(x = quarter_floor,
                          y = n_quarter_scaled, 
                          color = Injury.Cause))+
  scale_x_date() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . *(max(df_for_plot_2$n_quarter) / max(df_for_plot_1$n_quarter))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understood how you want to show data for each month and also summarise for each 3 months, so I did both but separated.

### Summarise (3 months)

In the package `lubridate` we have the function `quarter`, that divide the year into fourths

```
df %>% 
  group_by(quarter = quarter(Date)) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(n,na.rm = TRUE)) 

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  quarter total
    <int> <int>
1       1    49
2       2     9
```

### Two y axis

To create an axis with a diffent scale is very hard, and not recommend in `ggplot2`, but you can create a secondary axis using a function with the main axis scales

```
df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(Date, n, color = Injury.Cause, group = Injury.Cause) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0,150,10),
    limits = c(0,150),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.,breaks = seq(0,80,10))
  )
```

[image]